# Why is my headers are not in right position after php codes are implemented?

Tags: php, html, css

I was working on my term project i fetched data from api and print with php on my html page but after adding my php codes, my main headers are looks broken in the picture below.

[image]

So i tried many times to fix this problem using some other divs, make some changes on my css file etc. but still the same result.

here is my code:

```
<div class="topRated">
    <h1>Top Rated Movies</h1>
        <?php
            //echo ' <h1>Top Rated Movies</h1>';

            $id_movie = urlencode("id");
            $data = file_get_contents("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=59419be18ecb300104521be9c3837f01&language=en-US&page=1");
            $data = json_decode($data,true);
            foreach($data['results'] as $result){
                echo '<div class="column">
                <div class="row">
                <a href="movie.php?id=' . $result['id'] . '"><img src="'."http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500".''. $result['poster_path'] . '" width="140" height="180"></a><h4><span style="color:#000000;text-align:center;">' . $result['original_title']. "</h4><h5><span style=color:#000000;text-align:center;>"." Rate : " . $result['vote_average'] . " | Vote : " . $result['vote_count'] ."</h5> </h6><span style=color:#000000;text-align:center;>"."Popularity : " . round($result['popularity']) . "</h6>
                </div>
                </div>";
                
            }
        ?>

</div>


<div class="popular">
    <h1>Popular Movies</h1>    
        <?php
            //echo '<h1>Popular Movies</h1>';
            $id_movie = urlencode("id");
            $data = file_get_contents("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=59419be18ecb300104521be9c3837f01&language=en-US&page=1");
            $data = json_decode($data,true);
            foreach($data['results'] as $result){
                echo '<div class="column">
                <div class="row">
                <a href="movie.php?id=' . $result['id'] . '"><img src="'."http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500".''. $result['poster_path'] . '" width="140" height="180"></a><h4><span style="color:#000000;text-align:center;">' . $result['original_title']. "</h4><h5><span style=color:#000000;text-align:center;>"." Rate : " . $result['vote_average'] . " | Vote : " . $result['vote_count'] ."</h5> </h6><span style=color:#000000;text-align:center;>"."Popularity : " . round($result['popularity']) . "</h6>
                </div>
                </div>";
                
            }
        ?>

</div>


<div class="upcoming">
    <h1>Upcoming Movies</h1>
        <?php

            //echo '<h1>Upcoming Movies</h1>';
            $id_movie = urlencode("id");
            $data = file_get_contents("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=59419be18ecb300104521be9c3837f01&language=en-US&page=1");
            $data = json_decode($data,true);
            foreach($data['results'] as $result){
                echo '<div class="column">
                <div class="row">
                <a href="movie.php?id=' . $result['id'] . '"><img src="'."http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500".''. $result['poster_path'] . '" width="140" height="180"></a><h4><span style="color:#000000;text-align:center;">' . $result['original_title']. "</h4><h5><span style=color:#000000;text-align:center;>"." Rate : " . $result['vote_average'] . " | Vote : " . $result['vote_count'] ."</h5> </h6><span style=color:#000000;text-align:center;>"."Popularity : " . round($result['popularity']) . "</h6>
                </div>
                </div>";
                
            }
        ?>


</div>
```

Also my css codes are in below:

```
.column {
height: 340px;
margin-top: 70px;
margin-left: 45px;
float: left;
width: 13%;
padding: 0px;
font-family: serif;
font-style: normal;
text-align: center;
display: inline;}

.row::after {
margin-left: 40px;
font-family: serif;
font-style: normal;
text-align: center;}
```

I didn't write any css codes for the div outside of the php codes. But i can't fix this problem.
How can i fix this?

Comment: What's the styles for `h1`? PHP likely is unrelated here, can you add rendered HTML as well?

Comment: How to fix - stop using outdated `float`. Use flexbox instead. As a quickfix CSS use something like `.topRated, .popular{ overflow: hidden }`. Or `h1{ clear: both }`

Comment: FYI: You got `column` and `row` rather backwards here.

Comment: Fyi, `</h6>` closes a heading, you want to open them first using `<h6>`

Comment: @user3783243 there is no styles for h1 besides i added the styles but nothing changed